# How to modify geometric figures having the TikZ code easily?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Let's say I have the code in TikZ for some geometric figures and I don't want to spend so much time making the changes directly over the TikZ code. So, I know that Geogebra can export TikZ code from pictures but I don't know if it's possible to do it the other way around. This is because having the TikZ code I'd like to make some changes on my pictures. My question is if this is possible and how or if there is an alternative to do it.

Comment: You want changes in the TikZ code to be synced with the GeoGebra file?

Comment: I don't think GeoGebra has any way of importing TikZ graphics, and in any case that would really be a question about GeoGebra, and hence off topic for this site.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The figures' TikZ code was generated by using GeoGebra. The problem is that I don't have the files but only the TikZ code so I'd like to know if it's possible to modify them again by using Geogebra or any other program.

Comment: If GeoGebra (or any other software) cannot import TikZ code the answer is no.

Comment: @DanielaDiaz, if you have the `tikz` code, run `pdflatex` on it and then you can open the `pdf` file using `inkscape` and change everything.

Comment: You can compile your TikZ code in a standalone PDF then edit this PDF via [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns features of an external tool not directly TeX'nFriends-related.